# Grouping rows based on a consecutive flag in SQL (Redshift)

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I've got a tricky problem that I am trying to solve here and can't get my head around it so far.

So the problem is this: I have tracking data, where there are records produced over time. Let's say you have a robot driving around and you record it's position once every second. Each of those positions is recorded as one record in the database (we use AWS Redshift).

Each record has a tracking_id which is unique across all records that belong to the same source of the tracking, i.e. unique for the robot. Then I have a record_id which is globally unique, a timestamp, and a flag that indicates if the record was created while the robot was inside or outside a defined zone. And then there is some additional data like coordinates.

Here is a little illustration. The pink box is the zone, the green line is the path of the robot and the blue dots are the produced records.
[image: Example path]

So now I would like to group records based on the zone flag (have a look at the screenshot below). So I want to isolate sub-paths inside the zone into a record and grab the start and end timestamp and position. The IDs don't matter so I don't necessarily need to keep the tracking or record ids even though I listed them in the desired result.

[image: Input and desired output]

Thanks for the help, I would really appreciate it! Also just solving part of the problem like how to group based on the flag without grabbing first and last values within the sub-paths would help already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a gaps and islands problem.  In this case, you want the islands where `in_zone` happens to be `TRUE` (and there are two of them).  We can use the difference in row number method here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tracking_id ORDER BY timestamp) rn1,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tracking_id, in_zone ORDER BY timestamp) rn2
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    tracking_id,
    MIN(record_id) AS record_id,
    MIN(timestamp) AS start_timestamp,
    MAX(timestamp) AS end_timestamp,
    (SELECT t2.coordinates FROM yourTable t2
     WHERE t2.record_id = MIN(t1.record_id) AND t2.tracking_id = t1.tracking_id) AS entry_coordinates,
    (SELECT t2.coordinates FROM yourTable t2
     WHERE t2.record_id = MAX(t1.record_id) AND t2.tracking_id = t1.tracking_id) AS exit_coordinates
FROM cte t1
WHERE
    in_zone = 'TRUE'
GROUP BY
    tracking_id,
    rn1 - rn2,
    in_zone
ORDER BY
    tracking_id,
    record_id DESC;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: Do you know how to do this when we cannot rely on the record_id to be ordered? since you ware working with the min and max in the inner queries, it won't work if the record id is for example a hash.

Comment: Well we could possibly use a correlated subquery to extract any `record_id` value you want per group.

Comment: I found a way by selecting from `cte` instead of `yourTable` in the subquery and then matching the record by `rn1` instead of record_id. So a subquery would look like this: `SELECT t2.coordinates FROM cte t2
     WHERE t2.rn1 = MIN(t1.rn1) AND t2.tracking_id = t1.tracking_id`

Answer (score 0):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem.  I would approach it using `LAG()` to identify the previous in-group and a cumulative sum.  You can also use conditional aggregation to get the first and last coordinate values:

```
SELECT tracking_id, MIN(record_id), MIN(timestamp) as start_timestamp,
       MIN(timestamp) as end_timestamp,
       MAX(CASE WHEN prev_in_zone IS NULL OR prev_in_zone <> in_zone THEN coordinates END) as entry_coordinates,
       MAX(CASE WHEN next_in_zone IS NULL OR next_in_zone <> in_zone THEN coordinates END) as entry_coordinates
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             SUM( CASE WHEN prev_in_zone = in_zone THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY tracking_id ORDER BY timestamp ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as grp
      FROM (SELECT t.*,
                   LAG(in_zone) OVER (PARTITION BY tracking_id ORDER BY timestamp) as prev_in_zone,
                   LEAD(in_zone) OVER (PARTITION BY tracking_id ORDER BY timestamp) as next_in_zone
            FROM t
           ) t
     ) t
WHERE in_zone = 'TRUE'
GROUP BY tracking_id, grp;
```

With much appreciation to Tim, [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2324a50fabc05d39e36b200d89fc6cdb) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks! This looks actually pretty great and also seems to be more performant than the other first approach. However, if I try to run it on redshift, I get the following error:
    [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Aggregate window functions with an ORDER BY clause require a frame clause;

If I add ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING to the window function, I only get one result per tracking_id because the grp is always the same in the inner query. Any idea?

Comment: @oneschilling . . . Yes, I tend to forget that requirement in Redshift.